# Pojo class in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, pojo

Hi I am new to Hibernate . I have a doubt.
I have a table User. Columns are Name ,Age and Location.
So my pojo class would be like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    private int Age;
    private String Location;
    private String Name;
//Getters and setters methods
```

Now can I have another static declaration (salary is not a field in the table)

```
private int salary;
```

Will hibernate assume that even salary as a column in the table User? 
What exactly is the function of a POJO class in hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all filds are persistent by default. If you want to have a field that is not persistet, you need to annotate it with `@Transient`:

```
@Transient
private int salary;
```

Of course, each time Hibernate will load a User from the database, the salary will have a default value (0, or the one set in the no-arg constructor of User).

Please respect the Java naming conventions: fields start with a lower-case letter. Also, using the age of a user as its ID doesn't mak much sense: several users will probably have the same age, and the age is a mutable value.

> What exactly is the function of a POJO class in hibernate?

Well, that's the definition of Hibernate: it's an ORM, which maps database tables to Java objects. Hibernate has a good documentation. Read it.